# Glitchy JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to web design and programming related to it. I'm making a simple gallery using JavaScript, I know it's extremely easy using jQuery. However I'm not allowed to use it (assignment).

Here's the code where the problem is:

```
var img = new Array(); //declared globally, accessed by other functions
function displayImage(){

var img_num = document.getElementById('img_num').getAttribute("value");

for(j=0;j<img_num;j++)
  img.push(document.getElementById('h'+j).getAttribute("value"));


var list_width = 0;
for(var i=0;i<img_num;i++) 
{      
   document.getElementById('list_holder').innerHTML += "<img src='" +img[i]+ "'onclick=\"show(this.id);\" height = \"70%;\"id='"+i+"'/>";
   list_width += document.getElementById(i).offsetWidth + 15;
}

document.getElementById('list_holder').style.width = list_width+"px";
return false;
}
```

Elements with ID's h0,h1,h2... and so on are hidden input types that contain the path of the image and ID's 0,1,2.. are  tags.

I'm using them in the JS to store the paths in an array `img` using `img.push`. Then I'm using the values in the array to create exactly that many `<img>` tags (with heights specified, and width left for the aspect ratio to decide. Now it is necessary for me to calculate the total **width** of the parent `div` ('list_width') of these `img` tags so I thought of using `list_width+=document.getElementById(i).offsetWidth`.

But what's happening is, when I open the page for the first time, the actual width is not being returned. It returns `4`, which is basically the min width of an  tag I figured. Only on refreshing the page it works as expected. I know I can use a work-around by refreshing the page once just after loading it, but I want to know if there's any 'preferred' or 'professional' way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are the curly braces? Your `for` loop doesn't affect `list_width += document.getElementById(i).offsetWidth + 15;`

Comment: remember that unlike python, haml etc, javascript doesn't care about indentation.

Comment: really sorry , that's not it, i actually removed several lines of debugging output and missed to the braces :P I'll edit that. In my code the brackets are all fine,

Comment: Maybe you calculate the width before the images are loaded. And after you reload the page they are already in the cache.

Comment: i thought of that too, but then if i use inspect element, i find that all the <img> tags are already loaded, and have been pushed out of the screen because of wrongly calculated width... if the img tags hadn't shown in the first place , it would've made sense that the `getElemenById(i)` is actually not finding any element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait until the images are loaded. You are new to Javascript but you already have to face asynchronous programming. Let's see this in the comments:

```
var img = []; // faster to type, use this syntax if you
              // don't define an initial length
function displayImage() {
    // The attribute value defines the initial value of the input element, and
    // it may differ from the actual value. So use the value property, not the
    // attribute.
    var img_num = document.getElementById('img_num').value;

    for(var j=0; j<img_num; j++) // Watch out, without var j is global!
        img.push(document.getElementById('h'+j).value);


    var list_width = 0,
        // We're referincing this element a lot, better store it
        lholder = document.getElementById('list_holder'),
        htmllist = []; // See the trick
    for(var i=0; i<img_num; i++)
        htmllist.push("<img src='" +img[i]
            + "'onclick=\"show(this.id);\" height = \"70%;\"id='"+i+"'/>");

    // Every time you set innerHTML, using = or +=, the browser has to parse
    // the code and rebuild the content, and it's an expensive task. Set this
    // property only once you already computed all the HTML you need.
    lholder.innerHTML = htmllist.join("");

    var loaded = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<img_num; i++)
        // You don't know when the images will be loaded. But when an image is
        // loaded, it triggers the load event that you can listen setting the
        // onload property (or, in a more modern way, setting an event listener
        // with addEventListener or attachEvent in older IE). Count the images
        // that are loaded, and when they're all loaded do your stuff.
        lholder.childNodes[i].onload = function() {
            if (++loaded < img_num) return;
            for(var i=0; i<img_num; i++)
                list_width += lholder.childNodes[i].offsetWidth;
            lholder.style.width = list_width + "px";
        };

    return false;
}
```

Comment: WOW thanks a Ton dude! But now there's seems to be a new problem (when i use your code) and it's even more absurd: the onclick for the img tags doesn't seem to be working! I inspected the elements in Chrome and they all do have the `onclick="show(this.id)` yet nothing is happening. The show() function basically shows an enlarged image at the center of the screen with the list of imgs inside 'list_holder' all at the bottom

Comment: Sorry! My bad! it's all working fine! Thanks a lot, again! There's one more thing though, while the onload waits for **all** the images to populate, it does show just the first image. How do i make it pop the images as each one loads? I tried by removing the `if` and `for` statement, expecting the onload to be called everytime the `i`th image was loaded, updating `list_width` and seting `lholder`'s width to that. But somehow the function is not getting called at all :/ how does the line `lholder.childNodes[i].onload` work exactly?

Comment: @Shark Just remove the `if` in the `onload` function, so each time an image is loaded the width of `#list_holder` is computed again. I guess `#list_holder` is an element with the `overflow` style property set to `hidden`?

Comment: yup exactly! `overflow-x` is set to `scroll`. I actually removed only the `if` first but then actually what it does is compute the value of `list_holder` in a nested loop , doing it several times more than is actually needed and making the length way too long. so i removed the for loop too, guessing that it would now do it only once, per each outer-loop iteration. However on putting some debugging output I found the `onload` was called only after all iterations were done. For eg let `img_num` be 7. I put in the an `alert(img_num)` inside the onload. A pop-up appears only once, showing `8` !

Comment: @Shark Have you tried with another browser? And what browser did you use, by the way?

Comment: @Shark "There" what? Sorry, I can't really debug your own code, you see. You can try learning all the goodies of Chrome's Developer Tools, starting from breakpoints and inspecting the Network tab. If you really can't get out of it, create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and open another question linking to it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you have to wait for the images to finish loading before querying the attributes. Here is an example of what is happening.

```
img {
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}
img:hover {
    width: 300px;
}

<div id="display" class="main"></div>

var display = document.getElementById("display"),
    images = {
        "F12berlinetta": "http://www.ferrari.com/Site_Collection_Image_115x55/f12_thumb_home_115x55.png",
            "458 Spider": "http://www.ferrari.com/Site_Collection_Image_115x55/110823_458_spider_menu.png",
            "FF": "http://www.ferrari.com/Site_Collection_Image_115x55/ff_thumb_home_115x55.png",
            "458 Italia": "http://www.ferrari.com/Site_Collection_Image_115x55/458_italia_menu_1_dx_ok.png",
            "Ferrari California": "http://www.ferrari.com/Site_Collection_Image_115x55/california_menu_3_sx.png"
    },
    keys = Object.keys(images),
    loaded = 0,
    menuWidth = 0,
    noWaitWidth = 0;

function clickedIt(evt) {
    alert("You chose the " + evt.target.title);
}

function onLoaded(evt) {
    loaded += 1;
    menuWidth += evt.target.offsetWidth;
    evt.target.addEventListener("click", clickedIt, false);
    if (loaded === keys.length) {
        console.log("Waited load width", menuWidth);
    }
}

keys.forEach(function (key, index) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"),
        newImg = document.createElement("img");

    newImg.id = "thumb" + index;
    newImg.src = images[key];
    noWaitWidth += newImg.offsetWidth;
    newImg.title = key;
    newImg.addEventListener("load", onLoaded, false);

    newDiv.appendChild(newImg);
    display.appendChild(newDiv);
});

console.log("Didn't wait load width", noWaitWidth);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/8JRwM/)

Addition: This places HTML image markup in the document in a standard javascript manner, if that is what you mean. Without you describing what you do not understand, it is difficult to simplify any explanation; There is an object that holds the image title and its URL. We loop through the object and place the image in the document along with the title and get the incorrect image width, on each image we set an event listener that waits for the image to load, when it loads we get the correct image width. We also set click listener on each image which gives an alert of which image you clicked. The CSS demonstrates its standard hover method, so that when you place the move over an image it zooms that image.

Comment: This is an example of the problem that you are having and an example of how the solution is implimented in javascript. I have not written your loader for you. i.e. my answer is general to javascript rather than specific to your code.

Answer (score 0):

This line has a problem:

```
for(var i=0;i<img_num;i++)       
   document.getElementById('list_holder').innerHTML += "<img src='" +img[i]+ "'onclick=\"show(this.id);\" height = \"70%;\"id='"+i+"'/>";
   list_width += document.getElementById(i).offsetWidth + 15;
```

since you don't have curley braces it will only run the first line in the loop, change it to this:

```
for(var i=0;i<img_num;i++){     
   document.getElementById('list_holder').innerHTML += "<img src='" +img[i]+ "'onclick=\"show(this.id);\" height = \"70%;\"id='"+i+"'/>";
   list_width += document.getElementById(i).offsetWidth + 15;
}
```

Comment: sorry i missed the braces while posting it here. after posting i removed some debugging output and forgot to put the braces, they are all correct in my original code